# loop and query is executing twice

Tags: vb.net

I am adding blogs in a website. that work like if i will click on the title link by the help of query string the page with title, desc, img will display.but at this particular time loop is executing two time.
here is my code pls help.

```
  Private Sub sbloadBlog()
    Try
        Dim unqstr As String = Request.QueryString("id").ToString()
        unqstr = unqstr.Substring(0, unqstr.IndexOf("-"))
        Dim x As String = "select distinct Title as url, img, blog_desc  from Blog_Gallery_AYS where unqid  ='" + unqstr + "'"
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = Dal.GettDS(x).Tables(0)
        x = ""
        x += "<p>"
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            x += "<h2>'" + dr("url") + "'</h2>"
            x += "<p>'" + dr("blog_desc") + "' </h2>"
            x += "</br>"
            x += "</br>"
            x += "<img src='" + dr("img").ToString().Replace("~/", "") + "'/>"

        Next
        x += "</p>"
        x += x.Replace("'", """")
        divblogdetail.InnerHtml = x
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing Then
        sbloadBlog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "If not me.IsPostBack" perform sbloadBlog()?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to verify if a page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.Page.IsPostBack Then
        If Not Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing Then sbloadBlog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: still having the same problem.i performed debugging the problem occur when i was at divblogdetail.InnerHtml = x. pls help